# Android custom account retreive the password

Tags: android, accounts

I've created a custom account according to doc, i have a class extending `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` and the service.

I add an account like this:

```
    public static void addCustomAccount(Context context, String title, String password) {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        Account account = new Account(title, Constants.ACCOUNT_KEY);
        if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null)) {
            Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, "Account in Android Accounts was created");
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, the account is displayed in the settings.

My question is:

> How can i retreive the password i've set in this procedure?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry had a typo

Comment: @cricket_007 oops, i can't even copy paste. should be good now...

Comment: There are several methods in the AccountManager class that are "getAccounts". Have you tried them?

Comment: @cricket_007 ofc. however if i get the correct account which i've added (this works) the `account` object has no field or method to retreive the password

Comment: No method?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword(android.accounts.Account)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, thats the method i couldn't find. i didn't expected it to be in accountmanager. thank you. If you wish add an answer and i'll tick it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`AccountManager#getPassword(Account account)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword(android.accounts.Account)) is what you need.

And you can get your Account object via the `getAccounts` method of the manager as well